# Laravel 6.0: Stripe credit card element not displaying

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, stripe-payments

I have my Stripe keys embedded in my code and my environment file. I also have my Stripe integration script placed here:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

<!-- Stripe integration -->
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

@section('content')
```

I also have the HTML element and the JavaScript code for Stripe in my checkout view:

```
<!-- STRIPE ELEMENTS -->
            <form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
                <div class="form-row">
                <label class="ml-1" for="card-element">
                    Credit or debit card
                </label>
                <div id="card-element">
                    <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                </div>

                <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
                <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <hr class="mb-4">
                <h3 id="no-products"></h3>
                <button id="submit-payment" class="btn btn-lg btn-block" type="submit"><b>Submit Payment</b></button>
            </form>
            <!-- END STRIPE ELEMENTS -->
```

```
<script>
        (function() {
        // creates a Stripe client
        var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_9dn1vt3i0j0Q5GZdwAXn9iUs00iMziQDyD');

        // creates an instance of Elements
        var elements = stripe.elements();

        var style = {
        base: {
            color: '#32325d',
            fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
            fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
            fontSize: '16px',
            '::placeholder': {
            color: '#aab7c4'
            }
        },
        invalid: {
            color: 'red',
            iconColor: 'red'
        }
        };

        // creates an instance of the card Element
        var card = elements.create('card', { style: style, hidePostalCode: true });

        // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
        card.mount('#card-element');

        // handles real-time validation errors from the card Element
        card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        if (event.error) {
            displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
        } else {
            displayError.textContent = '';
        }
        });

        // handles form submission.
        var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // disables the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        document.getElementById('submit-payment').disabled = true; 

        stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
            if (result.error) {
            // informs the user if there was an error
            // enables the submit button if validation fails
            document.getElementById('submit-payment').disabled = false;
            var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
            errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
            } else {
            // sends the token to the server
            stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
            }
        });
        });

        // submits the form with the token ID
        function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
        // inserts the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
        var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
        form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

        // submits the form
        form.submit();
        }
        })();
```

The dev console is recognising that Stripe exists and it's not showing any errors in the console. Yet, the input field to enter the credit card information does not appear. This is a replication from my previous project that works fine.

What could the solution be here?

Comment: Does your javascript have a `</script>` to close after your code? That's the only thing I see here. Otherwise when I paste this into a JSFiddle it works just fine, https://jsfiddle.net/kqyxhg2t/

Comment: Nope. I forgot to add the CSS!

Comment: @user12037570 Can you give a more detailed explanation? Mine is not showing and I want to make sure i am not making the same mistake